# Moving data from table to another based on an ID

Tags: mysql

I'm currently trying to add data from one table(stockroom) to another(order). In both tables, stock is assigned a code like A1A1. The Order table contains all of the codes to complete the order and the quantity needed (this is imported from an excel file) and the Stockroom table has all of the information about the stock like descriptions.

I would like to import the other data about the stock from the Stockroom table to the Order table base on the stock code. Here's my attempt:

```sql
INSERT INTO `database`.`order` 
(`VID`, `Supplier`, `Description`, `Cost per Unit`) 
select `VID`, `Supplier`, `Description`, `Cost` 
FROM `database`.`stockroom` 
WHERE `ID`="a1a1"
```

When I try the code above this appears:

> Error Code: 1364. Field 'ID' doesn't have a default value

Because ID (ID is the stock code) already has a value I don't want to assign it another. I tried inserting `` WHEN `ID`='A1A1' `` before `SELECT` to get around this but it just brings up a 1064 Error. Any advice?

Note: I'm not sure if this is relevant but I will be calling on this in a vb.net application

Comment: You must use UPDATE which changes the data in existing rows, not INSERT which inserts more rows.

Comment: try to learn about foreign key,you're using a wrong approach

Comment: @Akina I just tried changing to UPDATE but I kept stumbling across a 1054 error. It doesn't seem to like me referencing columns in other tables without me using FROM

Comment: @FatihaIMOUSSAINE I just did a quick google search and I think that might be what I'm looking for. I'll prob have to a bit more reading on it but thanks for pointing me in the right direction!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you need in something like

```sql
UPDATE order o
JOIN stockroom s USING (code)
SET o.VID = s.VID,
    o.Supplier = s.Supplier,
    o.Description = s.Description,
    o.`Cost per Unit` = s.Cost
-- WHERE s.ID = 'a1a1'
```

`USING (code)` uses the column which you mention in *In both tables, stock is assigned a code like A1A1*. Maybe it is ID or some another column.

WHERE clause is taken from your query but commented. Without it all rows which's `code` (see above) value is present in both tables will be updated.

Additionally you may add the checking that the value in upodated table.column is not set yet (is NULL), and update only it is empty. This checking may look like `SET o.VID = COALESCE(o.VID, s.VID)` - if `order.VID` is not empty it won't be updated.